# Dynamic pdf in php

Tags: php, tcpdf

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf.php');

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8');

$pdf->AddPage();

$font_path = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('fonts/Kokila.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->AddFont('Kokila', 'B', $font_path, true);
$pdf->SetFont('Kokila', 'B', 14);

$devanagariText = 'अक्षय : अक्षय';

$utf8Text = mb_convert_encoding($devanagariText, "UTF-8");

$pdf->Text(10, 90, $utf8Text);    

$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

i am getting this output
अकषय: अकषय

how to solve this type of font problem

this output अक्षय  i expected

Comment: TCPDF doesn't support Indic.